# CSS buttons aren't aligned

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create the following table: https://fiddle.jshell.net/7zrmd2wa/

The output is good on Fiddle, but if I host it myself then it outputs this, the buttons aren't aligned. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzejH.jpg

I've tested it with different browsers.

I don't understand why? And how can I solve it?

Comment: I am not able to tell them apart. Fiddle and the screenshot look the same for me.

Comment: @orabis I've cleared it up. The Betaal button on the image is a bit higher than the Person button, although it should be on the same level

Comment: I assume there is additional CSS involved on the page you use the buttons on that may have an impact on the height. Your class `.button` has a given height of 100% whereas the `.submitbutton` does not have it, resulting in a stretching left button and a smaller _betaal_ button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following and it should fix the problem. I was able to reproduce your issue when I started the code on a separate html file

```
#table1 td form{
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
#table1 td form{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: You may also set display to table-cell

Comment: Perfect. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS to get vertical centering in all cells:

```
td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in your stylesheet:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

Try this way: [jsfiddle edited](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7zrmd2wa/1/)

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I think the answer from Orabis is better

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the sample, it should work unless you've got some additionnal CSS.